# Printing from two dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.1

```
states = {state, abbr}
cities = {abbr, capital}
```

I'd like to print out `state, abbr, capital` or some other order of the 3 values.
I tried inverting the key, value pair in states with:

```
inv_states = {state: abbr for abbr, state in states.items()}
for abbr, capital in sorted(inv_states.items()):
         print(abbr, ':', capital)
```

Now I've got:

```
states = {abbr, state}
cities = {abbr, capital}
```

And then trying to create a new dict with (I don't fully understand the below code):

```
newDict = defaultdict(dict)
for abbr in (inv_states, cities):
         for elem in abbr:
                 newDict[elem['index']].update(elem)
fullDict = newDict.values()
print(fullDict)
```

But I'm getting a `string indices must be intergers` error.

Little help please. Or am I completely on the wrong path? Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `{state, abbr}`, this is a set, not dictionary.

Comment: Please look at how the question looks before you save your edit.

Comment: @squigglytail.. did you just re-edited your post? I edited it for some reason. Your codes should be in `code tags`, which you can add by adding `4 spaces` before your codes.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data is in dictionaries, (which it is not in your example code). It should be pretty straightforward to pring out the data you are looking for

```
for state, abbr in states.items():
   print('{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(state, abbr, cities[abbr]))
```

Comment: This won't work in Python 3.1 (as the question title requires); `print` should be a function.